# Insufficient cpu in Kubernetes multi node cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, containers, cpu

I am trying to deploy an application into my Kubernetes cluster. It is a multi node cluster. There are `3 m4.2xlrge` aws instances.

```
m4.2xlarge
vCPU :- 8
Memory :- 32
```

Now, in my `deployment.yaml` file for that service, I have mentioned

```
limit:
  cpu: 11
request:
  cpu: 11
```

It is giving error, `insufficient cpu` and container is not scheduling. I have already `(8*3)=24` CPU resources available and I requested for `11` CPU out of it. It should share the CPU resource across nodes. Is the `limit` and `request` CPU is applicable for the containers per node? That means, should I have atleast `11` CPU per aws instance?

Comment: If I recall correctly, depending on where the limit is specified it may try to find a single 11-core node.

Comment: The request/limits are *per-container* (see e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Pod is scheduled on a single Node.  The resource `requests:` help decide where it can be scheduled.  If you say `requests: {cpu: 11}` then there must be some single node with 11 (unreserved) cores available; but if your cluster only has 8-core m4.2xlarge nodes, no single node will be able to support this.  Kubernetes can’t “aggregate” cores across nodes in any useful way at this level.

If you’re requesting a lot of CPU because your process has a lot of threads to do concurrent processing, consider turning the number of threads down (maybe even to just 1) but then changing the `replicas:` in a Deployment spec to run many copies of it.  Each individual Pod will get scheduled on a single Node, but with many replicas you’ll get many Pods which can be spread across the three Nodes.

If your process really needs more than 8 cores to run, then you need individual systems with more than 8 cores; consider an m4.4xlarge (same RAM-to-CPU ratio) or a c4.4xlarge (same total RAM, twice the cores).

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a `limit` or `request` for a pod, it takes into account per node capacity of CPU or memory. In other words you can't have a Pod requesting more CPU or Memory which is available on a single worker node of your cluster, if you do it will go in `Pending` state and will not come up until it finds a node matching the `request` of the Pod.

In your case, worker node of size `m4.2xlarge` has 8 vCPUs, and in the deployment file you have requesed 11 vCPUs for the Pod. This will never work even though you have 3 nodes of size m4.2xlarge. A Pod always get scheduled on a single worker Node so it doesn't matter if the aggregate CPU capacity of your cluster is more than 11 vCPUs because a Pod will only be able to consume resources from a single worker node.

Hope this helps!